# Design Pattern: Managing an async task across application layers

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

New to writing async methods using Tasks in C#.  This is a question about how to architect calling an async task from across application layers.

I have a Data Access layer that makes REST calls to a server.  I have implemented Async methods for each server call, that each return a Task.

I have a Business Logic layer that makes the calls to the Data Access layer.  Requests to the business logic layer that are asynchronous take a callback, which would get executed once the Task completes using `ContinueWith()`.  Details of the asynchronous execution are thus contained to the Business Logic layer.

I'm wondering if this kind of design choice makes sense, or if it would be better for my Business Layer to pass the Task object up to its caller?

Here's an example of my `DateManager` which I have so far.  Without `await`, I wrote it like I have here.  However, from my view controller, calling `DateManager.GetTradeDate()` with the callback might be awkward now.

```
public class DateManager : IDateManager
{
    public void GetTradeDate(string dt, Action<string> callback)
    {
        DateManagerClient dmc = new DateManagerClient();
        Task<string> t = dmc.GetTradeDateAsync(dt);
        t.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            callback(x.Result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally the mantra for `async` has been "async all the way down".  That is, if any given method internally has an `async` operation, then it should `await` that operation and should itself be `async`.  All the way up to the top-level application technology which invokes it.  "Hiding" `async` operations behind synchronous operations is problematic.

Comment: It sound's a bit off, you should'nt need to provide a callback to an async method... You should simply need to await the async method and continue from there. But I might be misunderstanding the scenario, could you perhaps provide some code to illustrate what you have so far?

Comment: I'm using VS2010, so I don't have `await` and `async`. I tried doing it with callbacks with my business layer, but learned that I can just use Tasks instead, which I used with my RestClient.  Now I have two paradigms in place.  Added a code sample to show how I'm doing it.  But, I like @David's advice that the async pattern should be repeated.

Comment: @gdbj: Whether using `async`/`await` or otherwise, I think the overall rule should still hold.  As much as possible, expose the tasks all the way back up to the top level.  Let the consuming application/technology handle the synchronization of tasks.  If you still have to manually write code to handle it, that's fine.  I just strongly feel that code should be in the application layer unless there's a truly compelling reason otherwise.  And when there is such a reason, be *very* careful not to re-invent the `async void` anti-pattern.  Make sure error cases are handled.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can't use the async/await keywords I would still suggest returning the task to the caller.

I suggest this because of a few reasons:

1. If you provide a callback (like in your example), you also have to specify the callbacks input parameters (in your example that is a string) and return type. This is an unneccesary limitation
2. It's a bit closer to the async/await pattern, thus if you at some Point will be implementing it, then it won't be such a big change in the code.
3. It's cleaner to keep the buisness code in the buisness layer and the callers code in whatever layer the caller is in (instead of injecting the callers code into the buisness layer)

As you might notice, it's mostly my opinion speaking here (except for #1, thats a pretty solid benefit). But it's the best answer I can give with the experience I have (I have also used tasks without async/await and boy was it a pain)